# Has facebook changed its image rendering logic recently?

Tags: facebook, image, google-chrome

Since the past few months, I've been noticing that they tend to some kind of pixelated image first which then gets replaced by a much better image.

Is this some kind of trick to reduce perceived latency by facebook?

Or is it Chrome doing it?

Answer (score 4):

i think it's [progressive image rendering](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html). Quote from the linked blog

> Images already render progressively in a web browser -- but you can do even better. Simply save your GIF or PNG images with the "interlaced" option, or your JPEG images with the "progressive" option.

Answer (score 2):

This blog might answer your query - checkout following links -

[Image Optimization Part 3: Four Steps to File Size Reduction](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/11/14/imageopt-3/)

[Image Optimization Part 4: Progressive JPEG…Hot or Not?](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/12/05/imageopt-4/)